# "Ski in / Ski out" – Which action is which?

Tags: phrases

Hotels on ski fields directly connected to the lift system are often referred to as "ski in / ski out" hotels.

In this context, does "ski out" refer to the action of skiing out *to* the mountain, or skiing out of the mountain *back to* the hotel (with "ski in" being the opposite)?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think this might just be a humorous offshoot of [drive-in drive-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-in_drive-out) (or _fly-in fly-out_), designed to emphasize how the hotel is an idyllic getaway spot.

Comment: I think there's some form of outdoor activities SE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ski-in/ski-out hotel is one where you can arrive and leave on skis. *Out* is leaving the hotel; *in* is going in.

> Imagine a ski holiday where you can walk out your front door and straight onto the slopes. No walking in ski boots, no bus rides, simply step into your skis or snowboard and start skiing.
>
> igluski.com: [Ski-in Ski-out Chalets and Hotels](http://www.igluski.com/chalets/ski-in-ski-out)

It's akin to a roll-on/roll-off ferry, where *on* is on to the ferry, not the quayside. The prepositions refer to the main noun: on to the ferry, into the hotel.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but it leaves it puzzling why *in* comes before *out* in the phrase, given that one first goes out of the hotel for a period of skiing, and then, later in the day, comes back in. (One is presumably not on one's skis when one arrives to check into the hotel.)

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer is counter to my understanding which is that the "in" and "out" are from the mountain perspective where the skiing happens. In other words, you ski "in" to the mountain and then you ski "out" from the mountain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).